# Ending undo transaction in macro in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint, undo

As described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278591 PowerPoint will usually combine all changes that a macro or add-in makes to a single undo step. So if you put the following code into VBA and execute it twice by pressing F5 there 
will only be one undo step.

```
Sub Move()
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
        ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 10
    End If
End Sub
```

I am looking for a way to change this behavior in a more complex scenario where the user can make multiple changes without directly accessing PowerPoint. Ideally, it should be possible to undo a set of modifications that corresponds to one change from the user's perspective.

What I found out is that ExecuteMso seems to break the undo transaction. So if you execute the following code twice it results in 4 undo steps (first increment, ExecuteMso, second increment, ExecuteMso).

```
Sub Move()
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
        ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 10
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Bold"
    End If
End Sub
```

Anyone knows a real solution for the problem or a better workaround? Although I didn't find it maybe there is a solution for Word or Excel that can be ported to PowerPoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace the `ExecuteMso` line with this one, the entire procedure remains one Undo:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextEffect.FontBold = msoTrue
```

**Update**

If you are using PowerPoint 2010 or later put this line before each block of code that you want the user to be able to undo a step at a time:

```
Application.StartNewUndoEntry
```

Comment: I guess I did not make it fully clear in the original post: I want **each execution** of the procedure to correspond to **one undo step**. Your suggestion would result in a single step for multiple executions.

The ExecuteMso workaround was the closest I got to the desired behavior that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: Hopefully you are using PowerPoint 2010 because there is a new command that should do the trick: ``Application.StartNewUndoEntry``. Put this before each line of code that you want to undo.

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for! Usually we use PowerPoint 2010 so I will use the function you recommended. To be on the safe side I will include the ExecuteMso workaround for PowerPoint 2007 unless you have another suggestion.

Comment: @RachelHettinger if I see this correctly your answer was accepted because of your comment... you might want to update the answer accordingly (I initially wondered why your answer is accepted until I read the comments)

Comment: Is there an equivalent to Application.StartNewUndoEntry for Excel? I can't really find anything when searching for a similar sub for Excel. It looks like you need to create such "restore points" manually in Excel?